# My tag "proof-verification" is automatically changed to "solution-verification"

Tags: discussion, tagging

Recently, when I added tag [proof-verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-verification) for my questions, it was then changed to [solution-verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification).

Could you please explain the reason for this phenomenon?

Comment: This happens when one tag is designated a *synonym* of the other.

Comment: Related: [Why does the tag “(solution-verification)” show as “(proof-verification)”?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27197) and [What is the usefulness of having “proof-verification” and “solution-verification” as different tags?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16973) I will mention that the direction (i.e., which of two tags is the master tag) was changed [relatively recently](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52903143#52903143).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105182/discussion-on-question-by-navier-stokes-my-tag-proof-verification-is-automatic).